# Paging can not start when reaching the end of UICollectionView. Horizontal UICollectionView inside UIscrollView which is inside UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

iOS 9+ , Swift 3.2.

```html
>> PageViewController
  >> UIViewController
     >> scrollView (just a UIScrollView)
        >> UICollectionView (.horizontal)
```

I'm using a UIPageViewController having horizontal UICollectionView inside UIScrollView in the second page. When scrolling horizontally in my UICollectionView, if I reach the left end of my UICollectionView, it does not changes the page of my UIPageViewController to the previous page. (In the case when uiCollectionView is inside uiPageViewController ( without scrollView) everything works).

What should I do to reach the left end of uiCollectionView (first cell) and immediately start a process of paging to the previous page with the same swipe gesture?